# How to pass IP addresses from database to a geo locator and return data?

Tags: java, sql, geolocation, ip, ip-address

OK guys, I know that there are many questions already posted about getting location data from IP addresses but my questions is slightly unique; plus I still don't posses enough understanding of the concepts posted in those discussions to piece together my particular puzzle.

In my Java program I pull data from a database that houses security threat information including the attacking IP. I want to use that attacking IP address in a geo locator and then display it in my GUI.

Most of the other questions that refer to this IP location concept deals with javascript which leaves me a little left out. I have also seen geoGoogle API recommended but it seems as though they now have a limit: http://geo-google.sourceforge.net/index.html

What would be the best way on going about this, or maybe what tool is best suited? I'm a beginner programming and I'm afraid I have just about no experience in dealing with this type of problem/task.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Java, you might want to look into MaxMind's free [GeoLite database](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/). You do not need a SQL server to use it as the [Java API](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/downloadable/#Java) reads the data directly from the database file. You can download the API directly from the MaxMind website or from the Maven Central Repository.

Here is an example of how you use the GeoIP Java API:

```
LookupService ls = new LookupService("/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat");
Location location = cl.getLocation("213.52.50.8");
System.out.println(location.countryName);
System.out.println(location.city);
...
```

You may also want to see [this tutorial](http://www.codereye.com/2010/01/calculate-distance-between-2-ips-in.html) and [this example](https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-java/blob/master/CityLookupTest.java).

MaxMind also provides [paid web services](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/web-services/), if you prefer going that route.